# What is a function that is both bounded and continuous on $(1,2)$ but not uniformly continuous on the interval?

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity, bounded-variation

I have been seriously thinking about what I could use to answer this question and I just can't think of anything. I have tried doing $\frac{1}{x}$, $e^x$ and even considered $\tan(x)$. Maybe $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ could work? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Try $\sin\frac{1}{x-1}$.

Comment: $y=\sin(1/x)$ works if your interval was $(0,1)$. Now shift right one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How do I decide what to assign as delta in a proof for the continuity of sin(1/x)??

Comment: @JohnWarts If you are talking about uniform continuity, you probably have a theorem that says "if f and g are continuous, then their composition is continuous", with some appropriate restrictions. $1/x$ and $\sin$ are both continuous, ergo,

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. Unfortunately my small brain fails to comprehend this, I've been trying to do it for more than 4 hours now. I would love to see a proof of it if you guys have one. Otherwise, I hope whoever searches this in the future has more luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is bounded so there is no infinite limit possible at the lower or upper bound of the interval (i.e in $1$ or $2$).

If you can extend the function by continuity to the closed interval $[1,2]$, this will make it continuous on a compact set and therefore uniformly continuous.

So you are searching for a function that is continuous on $(1,2)$ but with no one side limit in $1^+$ or in $2^-$, since you are constrained by boundedness, it means that $f(x)$ should take infinitely many times different values whatever small the interval $[1,1+\epsilon)$ is, and since it is continuous, $f$ has to oscillate very quickly between some extremum values.

One such example is $f(x)=\sin(\frac 1{x-1})$ which has the whole segment $y\in[-1,1]$ as an adherent value for $y=f(x)$ in neighborhood of $1^+$, therefore not uniformly continuous.

---

Edit: answering your question in comment

The delta is not very important, just take $\epsilon=\frac 12$ for instance there is always an $x_n=1+\frac 1{(2n\pm\frac 12)\pi}$ such that $f(x_n)=\pm 1\notin[\ell-\epsilon,\ell+\epsilon]$ and $|x_n-1|<\delta$ for $n$ large enough.

*i.e. you found two values more than $2\epsilon$ apart, so it is impossible to find a suitable potential limit $\ell$ such that $|f(x_n)-\ell|<\epsilon$.*